# I'm missing template proposal in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, rest-assured

```
public class Basics {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // validate if Add Place API is working as expected
    
        // given - all input details 
        // when - Submit the API
        // then  - validate the response
        RestAssured.
    }

}
```

I'm not able to see any template proposal in my code set up

Comment: What are you doing to have them show, and *where*? What shows instead? Can you explain anything about the project so we know that there should be something showing?

Comment: If you have a `module-info.java` file, did you add the `requires ...` statement for REST Assured? If this does not help, please show your project structure, how you add the REST Assured dependency to the Java Build Path and in case `module-info.java` exists, also the content of your `module-info.java`.

Comment: Hi , I'm trying to input details by "given" method and when I try to go with : Rest Assured.b it should automatically show me the template proposal as RestAssured.baseURI ="https://rahulshettyacademy.com"; so even after manually adding by : import static io.restassured.RestAssured ; and import static io.restassured.RestAssured ; I'm still can't see template proposals I also add manual by going through steps provided in this video and no success : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l8pIEnUiYb8&ab_channel=TEJHOST Thank You in advance @nitind and howlger